# Is there a "res.status()"?

Tags: node.js

I've just started building a web server and an API. I want to send a response but I get an Error.

I've seen multiple documentations referring to a

```
res.staus(200).json({Some Json})
```

but I just get an error.

Here is my code:

```
    const http = require("http");

    const server = http.createServer((req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).json ({
            message: "should get this"
        });
    });

    server.listen(3000);
```

I expected to get the json in the web browser when I entered `localhost:3000`, but I don't.

I get an error:

> res.status(200).json ({
>        ^
>   TypeError: res.status is not a function

I can't find the function in the official Node.js http documentation, so my question: is there a res.status function? If not, why are there so many examples that use it?

Comment: I believe `createServer` should receive the express app, not a middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `status(200).json(output)` is the express syntax. The http syntax is like this:

```
res.statusCode = 404;
res.write('your json string');
// Or if you want to end the output writing
res.end('your json string');
```

You can also specify the status code by using the `writeHead` method, example:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.end('okay');
```

Good luck, find more information on the http nodejs module here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html